# How to add applications to Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda Navigator on both my Windows and Linux machines. On my Linux machine, the My Applications section of Anaconda Navigator showed the options I expected - IPython/Jupyter Notebook, Spyder, etc., but nothing popped up on my Windows. How do I add applications to the navigator?

Btw,  I also have Launcher installed on Windows and it gives me all the same applications I expect to see in the navigator. Is having this messing things up?